# How to handle 2 hoses going into 1 standpipe

Tags: drain, washing-machine, hose

I have a tiny sink in the basement with a hot/cold faucet and a standpipe, for our clothes washer. Got a new washer, and I'm having problems figuring how to attach everything up:

1. The attachment I have now seems to be a "standpipe adapter" - it has a ribbed nozzle that brings the 1 1/4" washer drain hose down to where it will fit in the standpipe (and it's not easy, I have to shove it in there and attach with zipties so it doesn't fly out when water's coming through it).
2. When we got the furnace put in, the installers ran a small plastic tube from the furnace into the standpipe. It looks like they gouged a hole out of the old standpipe adapter to get the drain to accept both water sources. (see photo)

My problem is finding a new solution for this:

Standpipe adapters seem to cost up to $50 for the small rubber/vinyl piece, plus a lot of shipping, and they're all brand-specific so I'm not sure if they will fit to a standard drain hose I can get at the hardware store. And none of the ones I've seen so far have the handy groove going all the way down the side like my old one (see photo). In addition, I'm not sure what tool I'd use to drill the new hole. I've seen a few Y-style adapters, but they're also expensive and I'm not sure if they would work right without spending the money to order and try them out.

Any ideas for what is the right part, or the right solution for this kind of problem? I've been leery of hiring a professional installer or plumber for what seems like it should be a $5-10 part. (By the way, that one in the photo won't come off of the old drain, it's either 1 piece or fused completely onto the hose).

Thanks for your help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't you leave one of the hoses in the sink with a J hook at its end?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the standpipe and sink as well?

Comment: Something you might now know is that the washing machine drain is NOT supposed to be air-tight to the standpipe, it needs to be smaller that the standpipe or otherwise vented. I think that's what the strange slot in the side of it is - a place for air to enter.

Comment: @r13 As you can tell from the photo, it's not a real sink, its just a sink-like box with a standpipe sticking up in the middle.

Comment: @Ariel posted the photo - hard to see since it's attached, but basically a PVC pipe sticking up in the middle of that box.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't call it a sink (as it has no drain) but a compartment. Is the standpipe a PVC or steel pipe?

Comment: @r13 Standpipe is PVC, 2" (posted more pictures)

Comment: I think it pays to add a real sink below the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That standpipe hole is MUCH too small - it's required to be at least 2", and you said it's less than 1 1/4? You should remove that box and replace it with a good one. Once it's large enough you'll have no trouble putting in the second drain line from the furnace.

How big is the pipe under the box? Is it vented?

This video is helpful for some nuances you might not realize: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzMURfc3Fgo

BTW you don't actually need a box (if you don't have the budget for it), you can literally just stick the drain hose into the top of a PVC pipe, but the pipe must be large enough! And it must be the right height, it must be vented, and you need a trap. (You need all that stuff with a box as well.)

If you like, post some pictures of the drain with the washing machine line removed, and of the PVC under the box.

Comment: I watched the video - trap and the venting looks good. The standpipe looks like 2", fitted into what looks like a standard box. So the width should be standard? Undoing the hose is hard, I have to balance it back up and add 2 zipties before I can use the washer again (maybe this weekend) - but it appears to be slightly narrower than the 2" pipe. The Maytag line I'm replacing I would guess is 1 1/4 - but I see the new hose I bought on Amazon is actually only a half inch, so that might work. Is there a difference between using a large and small drain hose, or does it maybe vary by manufacturer?

Comment: I disassembled and got pictures of the washer box. It's a bit hard to be exact, but the hole looks like about 1 1/8 inches (epoxied to the 2" standpipe). I also took a picture of a hose I bought online - it's about 1/2", which would work fine with the second hose, but I'm a little bit worried about too much water through the hose. Is any hose OK? No one at LG is willing to give me details about the size of their hose ends or hose requirements other than "order this standard replacement part."

Comment: Oh... they didn't cut the ring out correctly +1, which is a pita holding it in your hands... now it's stuck to the wall and pipes are in the way.

Comment: @orbfish So looks like the hole is 1 inch? How big is the black pipe under it? You might need to just remove and replace that wall box. Or maybe you can cut it larger, but you'll need to remove it, to avoid clogging your pipes with bits of plastic.

Comment: @Ariel The standpipe is 2", so it's just the drain that's 1 1/8". What do you mean about it's stuck to the wall and pipes are in the way? It's a regular box as if it was imbedded in a wall, but since it's a brick wall they just attached it to the plaster/bricks. And what do you mean by it was cut out incorrectly?

Comment: @orbfish That was someone else writing that, but basically the hole in the box should also be 2". So it's too bad it was not cut correctly because now it's hard to do. But that's what you need to do - cut the hole larger, or replace the box. Looks closely at the box, does it have an outline or indent or anything like that showing where to cut it?

Comment: @Ariel Well I couldn't find an outline. Eventually got a plumber in, since I thought the box would need replaced and I didn't think I could handle the copper piping for the water, but he was able to take a small drill bit and drill out a 2" outline at the bottom of the box and pop the edges out without letting plastic fall into the pipe. You got me there thanks for the help!

Comment: @orbfish Glad for the help I was able to provide.